# Asp.net mvc output cache don't work with RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

For my case, i have a controller, which query then forward the user using RedirectResult, which actually did a header "Location".

Then i apply the cache to the controller like this

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "none", NoStore=false)]
```

I try to re-run the page, and I check on my Linq profiler, I still able to see all the query of that page re run in like 1s.

How can I prevent this from happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if anybody can help you.  I think we need to see the controller actions.

Comment: what do you mean by this? i thought that the output cache will cache all the page, include the header, am i correct? if it include the header, it should not run the controller again, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the manual cache, instead of using output cache, which will cache your queries:

```
public IQueryable<Category> FindAllCategories()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["AllCategories"] != null)
        return (IQueryable<Category>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["AllCategories"];
    else
    {
        IQueryable<Category> allCats =  from c in db.Categories
                                          orderby c.Name
                                          select c;

        // set cache
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("AllCategories", allCats, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        return allCats;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer you found, you should consider accepting it.